# How to create data structure that supports carousel behavior?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

It's a simple Vue.js test application and the code looks as following:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="onPrevious">Previous</button>
    <button @click="onNext">Next</button>
    <br><br>
    <div v-for="(a, index) in chunkedArr()" :key="index">
      <div v-for="(i, index) in a" :key="index">{{ i }}</div>
      -
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
      newInput: [],
      currentIndex: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const temp = []

    for (let i = 0; i < this.input.length; i += 3) {
      let chunk = this.input.slice(i, i + 3)
      if (chunk.length === 1) {
        chunk = chunk.concat(this.input.slice(0, 2))
      }
      if (chunk.length === 2) {
        chunk = chunk.concat(this.input.slice(0, 1))
      }
      temp.push(chunk)
    }
    this.newInput = temp.flat()
  },
  methods: {
    chunkedArr() {
      if (this.newInput.length === 0) {
        return
      }

      const output = []

      for (let i = this.currentIndex; i < this.newInput.length; i += 3) {
        let chunk = this.newInput.slice(i, i + 3)
        output.push(chunk)
      }

      console.log(output)

      return output
    },
    onNext () {
      this.chunkedArr()
    },
    onPrevious () {
      // TODO
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

We could simulate carousel with Next and Previous buttons. Suppose we have some array of elements that should be displayed in carousel.

**But, in this carousel we should display 3 elements at once. It means 3 elements should be visible only on each click Next/Previous. For example, if we have an array of elements: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, the initial state is to display: 1, 2, 3.** On first click on Next, carousel should display 4, 5, 6 and so on. There are 3 cases at the end of array. The array can have 1, 2 or 3 elements at the end. If it has 3 elements, everything is easy. But if it has 1 or 2 elements, we need to add 2 or 1 elements respectively. In case of having 1 element at the end we need to add first 2 elements of array in order to display 3 elements. In case of having 2 elements at the end (our test case) we need to add first element only in order to display 3 elements. The rotating should go further based on previously described scenario.

Please, take a look at the screenshot attached:

[image]

In real case I need that data structure for BootstrapVue's Carousel.

UPDATE:

There are 4 subarrays in output array. Please, take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: You say subarrays, but in your example of output there are no subarrays. Just double space instead of nested [].  You should make it clear..

Comment: And what if no element is missing. Is the newInput still same?

Comment: If the element isn't missing, the array could look as following: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12. That is we immediately have all subarrays with 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const subArrayIterator = subArrayGenerator(example);
console.log('init: ' + subArrayIterator.next().value); // init

const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
prevBtn.onclick = () => {
  console.log(subArrayIterator.next(false).value);
}
nextBtn.onclick = () => {
  console.log(subArrayIterator.next().value);
}

function* subArrayGenerator(inputArray, subArrayLength=3) {
  let prev = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length;) {
    if (prev) {
      let diff = subArrayLength*2;
      if (diff > inputArray.length) {
        diff = diff % inputArray.length;
      }
      diff = i - diff;
      i = diff < 0 ? inputArray.length + diff : diff;
    }
    const subArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < subArrayLength; j++) {
      subArray.push(inputArray[i]);
      i = i < inputArray.length - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;
    }
    prev = (yield subArray) === false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="prev">prev</button>
<button type="button" id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the most likely I haven't described clearly in my first post what I needed. Please, take a look at updated post.

Comment: @tesicg and why did you talk about F5?

Comment: I've tried to make some kind of carousel simulation, but I think it's better with "Next/Previous" buttons.

Comment: In case when input array looks as following: const example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; and when we go previous, there is one "null" value in triplet. Please, take a look at UPDATE section in the original post.

Comment: I've changed: const diff = i - (subArrayLength * 2) to: const diff = i - ((subArrayLength - 3) * 2) and I think I get the correct result on prev: [1,2,3], [4,5,1], [2,3,4], [5,1,2], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

1. Rotate the array by appending a *s**p**lice* of `input` from `0` to `currentIndex`:

   ```js
   input.push(...input.splice(0, currentIndex))
   ```
2. Pad the array to a max length of 12 by appending a *slice* of `input` from `0` to the pad length:

   ```js
   while (12 - input.length > 0) {
     input.push(...input.slice(0, 12 - input.length))
   }
   ```
3. Split the array into slices of 3 by `Array(size).fill().map()`:

   ```js
   const output = Array(Math.ceil(input.length / 3)).fill().map((_, i) => input.slice(i * 3, i * 3 + 3))
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YzppJBq)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the most likely I haven't described clearly in my first post what I needed. Please, take a look at updated post.

Comment: The array is not limited to 12 elements. It can contain a lot of elements.